# How to use JavaScript RegExp to resolve relative paths?

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a utility method, which can be used to resolve relative paths.
The method should be implemented using JavaScript RegExp, and the algorithm is required as follows:

1) All occurrences of "**segment**/../", where **segment** is a
              complete path segment not equal to "..", are removed.
              Removal of these path segments is performed iteratively,
              removing the leftmost matching pattern on each iteration,
              until no matching pattern remains.

2) If the path ends with "/..", where  is a
              complete path segment not equal to "..", that
              "/.." is removed.

Examples:

```
a/b/css/../../d  ==> a/d
a/b/c.ss/../../d ==> a/d
a/b/css/../..    ==> a/
a/bss/../../../  ==> ../
../../../        ==> ../../../
```

I have tried to implement this method:

```
var result = "a/b/c.ss/../../d";

while(result.indexOf('..') >= 0)
{
   var temp = result.replace(/([^\.\/]*)\/\.\.\/?/,'');
   if (temp == result){
       break;
   }
   result = temp;
}
```

But it can't deal with "a/b/c.ss/../../d", so how can I correct it?

please help me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use a regular expression. I would split the path on the `/` and then iterate over the array and remove elements accordingly.

For example:

```
function resolve(path) {
    var parts = path.split('/');
    var i = 1;
    while (i < parts.length) {
        // if current part is `..` and previous part is different, remove
        // both of them
        if (parts[i] === '..' && i > 0 && parts[i-1] !== '..') {
            parts.splice(i-1, 2);
            i -= 2;
        }
        i++
    }
    return parts.join('/');
}
```

Comment: Why don't you start with `i = 1`?

Comment: This doesn't give the desired result for `a/b/css/../..`

Comment: `return parts.join('/') + (parts[parts.length -1] === undefined ? '/' : '');`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: True, though I'm not sure what's the rule here. In case of `a/b/css/../../d`, there is no trailing slash either, so why should there be one for `a/b/css/../..`. This seems to be somehow arbitrary.

Comment: You should keep your `i > 0` check for `'../../../'`.

Comment: @Felix Kling, thanks to you very much! I have tested it, but why "a/bss/../../../" results empty, and "a/b/css/../.." results "a", not "a/" ?

Comment: +1 because Regex is not always the solution to the problem (especially when path separators are easily defined and divided)

Comment: @lmnbeyond: Right. I thought if I start with `i = 1`, that condition is fulfilled anyway, but I forgot that I'm decreasing `i` as well. Should work again.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want, though Felix's answer should also work well once tweaked.

```
var tests = ['a/b/css/../../d','a/b/c.ss/../../d','a/b/css/../..','a/bss/../../../','../../../']
for(var i in tests)
{
    var result = tests[i];
    //you want from here..
    while(result.indexOf('..') >= 0 && result.match(/^\/?(\.\.\/)+\/?$/)==null)
    {
       var temp = result.replace(/([^\/]*)\/\.\.\/?/,'');
       if (temp == result){
           break;
       }
       result = temp;
    }
    //..to here
    console.log(tests[i]+'  |->|  '+result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you very much! I have tested it, and "../../a/bss/../../" results empty, should it be "../../"?